# IIS 10 Bad Request - Invalid URL code 400

Tags: iis, web-config, spree, windows-server-2019

I am using IIS to reverse proxy requests to a Spree Commerce backend server running on the same domain (port 4000) but is on a different machine. My rewrite rule for proxying looks like this:

```
            <rule name="Spree backend reverse proxy" stopProcessing="true">
                <match ignoreCase="true" url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^\/api/v2/storefront(\/.*)?" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^\/rails(\/.*)?" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:4000/{R:0}" redirectType="Found"
                    appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```

Most of my requests get proxied correctly. For some requests looking for an image, the spree backend redirects to another url. In such cases I am getting a 400 error with "Bad Request - Invalid URL" . The following path is initially requested:

```
/rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBIZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--eaf0cd5b8918b5b97f261c07fe6de1d8434cea0a/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCem9MWm05eWJXRjBTU0lJY0c1bkJqb0dSVlE2RkhKbGMybDZaVjkwYjE5c2FXMXBkRnNIYVFMQUVta0MwQWM9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJ2YXJpYXRpb24ifX0=--af08f06f4ce9755789c19150c3998b9022e0f51d/DALL%C2%B7E%202023-12-06%2014.35.19%20-%20Create%20an%20image%20that%20features%20a%20wide%20banner%20with%20a%20background%20pattern%20of%20black%20carbon%20fiber.%20Add%20dynamic%20splashes%20of%20mud%20across%20the%20banner,%20as%20if%20mud%20.png
```

IIS proxies the request to Spree, which redirects the user to the following path that returns the 400 error:

```
/rails/active_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--8165500c1e1645f6defeeaa959ef7fa6ac43e659/DALL·E%202023-12-06%2014.35.19%20-%20Create%20an%20image%20that%20features%20a%20wide%20banner%20with%20a%20background%20pattern%20of%20black%20carbon%20fiber.%20Add%20dynamic%20splashes%20of%20mud%20across%20the%20banner,%20as%20if%20mud%20.png
```

I tried using Failed Request Tracing but the requests aren't reaching IIS. I checked the HTTPERR logs as mentioned in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-http-400-errors-in-iis#troubleshooting-methods). Here's the last few lines of HTTPERR logs:

```
2023-12-12 22:22:19 209.115.235.218 53579 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_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--8165500c1e1645f6defeeaa959ef7fa6ac43e659/DALL%C2%B7E%202023-12-06%2014.35.19%20-%20Create%20an%20image%20that%20features%20a%20wide%20banner%20with%20a%20background%20pattern%20of%20black%20carbon%20fiber.%20Add%20dynamic%20splashes%20of%20mud%20across%20the%20banner,%20as%20if%20mud%20.png - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:22:19 209.115.235.218 53575 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkSFoxTkhWdU4yUTVOamRwYzJJNU5ucHFhR053WnpNMGFEaDVOQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVTJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFMUxURTVRMmhsZGxOMFpXRnNkR2d1YW5Cbklqc2dabWxzWlc1aGJXVXFQVlZVUmkwNEp5Y3hOUzB4T1VOb1pYWlRkR1ZoYkhSb0xtcHdad1k3QmxRNkVXTnZiblJsYm5SZmRIbHdaVWtpRDJsdFlXZGxMMnB3WldjR093WlVPaEZ6WlhKMmFXTmxYMjVoYldVNkNteHZZMkZzIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--7433e4073cbf604589aeb9fa1b3ffb0460a16c64/15-19ChevStealth.jpg - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:22:19 209.115.235.218 53615 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkemhwYjJwbE5XUnJiR0kwTkRjemJXWndabk40Wnpjd09IWnhZZ1k2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpYldsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFMUxURTVRMmhsZGpOcGJtTm9VSEpsY25WdWJtVnlMWFJvZFcxaUxtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuTVRVdE1UbERhR1YyTTJsdVkyaFFjbVZ5ZFc1dVpYSXRkR2gxYldJdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUTZFWE5sY25acFkyVmZibUZ0WlRvS2JHOWpZV3c9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--e1a4f59eb90fffb78601d97be3a83c1da0abe4c9/15-19Chev3inchPrerunner-thumb.jpg - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:22:19 209.115.235.218 53616 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhjREp5TURaM1lUazJNakJ3WkdVemVYZHJOR2h6YkhKdFptWndaQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVFdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpJd01URXRSbTl5WkMxUWNtVXVhbkJuSWpzZ1ptbHNaVzVoYldVcVBWVlVSaTA0SnljeU1ERXhMVVp2Y21RdFVISmxMbXB3WndZN0JsUTZFV052Ym5SbGJuUmZkSGx3WlVraUQybHRZV2RsTDJwd1pXY0dPd1pVT2hGelpYSjJhV05sWDI1aGJXVTZDbXh2WTJGcyIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--da14663b4859585715b3ec37761193ca0ed0414c/2011-Ford-Pre.jpg - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:22:19 209.115.235.218 53571 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhPSGRuYzJWallqSnllWG8zY25WNmJteHpjV2RtTkhBemVqVm1NQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVFdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFMUxURTVVbVZoY2pJdFJsTXVhbkJuSWpzZ1ptbHNaVzVoYldVcVBWVlVSaTA0SnljeE5TMHhPVkpsWVhJeUxVWlRMbXB3WndZN0JsUTZFV052Ym5SbGJuUmZkSGx3WlVraUQybHRZV2RsTDJwd1pXY0dPd1pVT2hGelpYSjJhV05sWDI1aGJXVTZDbXh2WTJGcyIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--ae89d426f1f28cfcdf14dfa70f03c767aa01b38b/15-19Rear2-FS.jpg - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:22:19 209.115.235.218 53620 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhjakZ1YTJSc2FHNW5hamN3Tm1FMk0ySXhaakJoYm5GbFlXUnBiUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpUjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFeFptOXlaRjl3Y21VdWFuQm5JanNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1VxUFZWVVJpMDRKeWN4TVdadmNtUmZjSEpsTG1wd1p3WTdCbFE2RVdOdmJuUmxiblJmZEhsd1pVa2lEMmx0WVdkbEwycHdaV2NHT3daVU9oRnpaWEoyYVdObFgyNWhiV1U2Q214dlkyRnMiLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--9c49fc8cba46d06a2f9d3bdd7e18484352fcd724/11ford_pre.jpg - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:22:44 209.115.235.218 53577 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhPSGRuYzJWallqSnllWG8zY25WNmJteHpjV2RtTkhBemVqVm1NQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVFdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFMUxURTVVbVZoY2pJdFJsTXVhbkJuSWpzZ1ptbHNaVzVoYldVcVBWVlVSaTA0SnljeE5TMHhPVkpsWVhJeUxVWlRMbXB3WndZN0JsUTZFV052Ym5SbGJuUmZkSGx3WlVraUQybHRZV2RsTDJwd1pXY0dPd1pVT2hGelpYSjJhV05sWDI1aGJXVTZDbXh2WTJGcyIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--ae89d426f1f28cfcdf14dfa70f03c767aa01b38b/15-19Rear2-FS.jpg - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:27:03 209.115.235.218 60071 10.50.7.10 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2023-12-12 22:27:03 209.115.235.218 60070 10.50.7.10 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2023-12-12 22:27:03 209.115.235.218 60075 10.50.7.10 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2023-12-12 22:27:03 209.115.235.218 60074 10.50.7.10 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2023-12-12 22:27:03 209.115.235.218 60076 10.50.7.10 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2023-12-12 22:32:50 209.115.235.218 60169 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkemhwYjJwbE5XUnJiR0kwTkRjemJXWndabk40Wnpjd09IWnhZZ1k2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpYldsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFMUxURTVRMmhsZGpOcGJtTm9VSEpsY25WdWJtVnlMWFJvZFcxaUxtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuTVRVdE1UbERhR1YyTTJsdVkyaFFjbVZ5ZFc1dVpYSXRkR2gxYldJdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUTZFWE5sY25acFkyVmZibUZ0WlRvS2JHOWpZV3c9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--e1a4f59eb90fffb78601d97be3a83c1da0abe4c9/15-19Chev3inchPrerunner-thumb.jpg 41 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:50 209.115.235.218 60169 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /rails/active_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--8165500c1e1645f6defeeaa959ef7fa6ac43e659/DALL%C2%B7E%202023-12-06%2014.35.19%20-%20Create%20an%20image%20that%20features%20a%20wide%20banner%20with%20a%20background%20pattern%20of%20black%20carbon%20fiber.%20Add%20dynamic%20splashes%20of%20mud%20across%20the%20banner,%20as%20if%20mud%20.png 43 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:50 209.115.235.218 60169 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhjakZ1YTJSc2FHNW5hamN3Tm1FMk0ySXhaakJoYm5GbFlXUnBiUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpUjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFeFptOXlaRjl3Y21VdWFuQm5JanNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1VxUFZWVVJpMDRKeWN4TVdadmNtUmZjSEpsTG1wd1p3WTdCbFE2RVdOdmJuUmxiblJmZEhsd1pVa2lEMmx0WVdkbEwycHdaV2NHT3daVU9oRnpaWEoyYVdObFgyNWhiV1U2Q214dlkyRnMiLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--9c49fc8cba46d06a2f9d3bdd7e18484352fcd724/11ford_pre.jpg 45 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:50 209.115.235.218 60169 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhPSGRuYzJWallqSnllWG8zY25WNmJteHpjV2RtTkhBemVqVm1NQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVFdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFMUxURTVVbVZoY2pJdFJsTXVhbkJuSWpzZ1ptbHNaVzVoYldVcVBWVlVSaTA0SnljeE5TMHhPVkpsWVhJeUxVWlRMbXB3WndZN0JsUTZFV052Ym5SbGJuUmZkSGx3WlVraUQybHRZV2RsTDJwd1pXY0dPd1pVT2hGelpYSjJhV05sWDI1aGJXVTZDbXh2WTJGcyIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--ae89d426f1f28cfcdf14dfa70f03c767aa01b38b/15-19Rear2-FS.jpg 47 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:50 209.115.235.218 60169 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkSFoxTkhWdU4yUTVOamRwYzJJNU5ucHFhR053WnpNMGFEaDVOQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVTJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFMUxURTVRMmhsZGxOMFpXRnNkR2d1YW5Cbklqc2dabWxzWlc1aGJXVXFQVlZVUmkwNEp5Y3hOUzB4T1VOb1pYWlRkR1ZoYkhSb0xtcHdad1k3QmxRNkVXTnZiblJsYm5SZmRIbHdaVWtpRDJsdFlXZGxMMnB3WldjR093WlVPaEZ6WlhKMmFXTmxYMjVoYldVNkNteHZZMkZzIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--7433e4073cbf604589aeb9fa1b3ffb0460a16c64/15-19ChevStealth.jpg 49 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:50 209.115.235.218 60169 10.50.7.10 443 HTTP/2 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhjREp5TURaM1lUazJNakJ3WkdVemVYZHJOR2h6YkhKdFptWndaQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVFdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpJd01URXRSbTl5WkMxUWNtVXVhbkJuSWpzZ1ptbHNaVzVoYldVcVBWVlVSaTA0SnljeU1ERXhMVVp2Y21RdFVISmxMbXB3WndZN0JsUTZFV052Ym5SbGJuUmZkSGx3WlVraUQybHRZV2RsTDJwd1pXY0dPd1pVT2hGelpYSjJhV05sWDI1aGJXVTZDbXh2WTJGcyIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--da14663b4859585715b3ec37761193ca0ed0414c/2011-Ford-Pre.jpg 51 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:59 209.115.235.218 60175 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhPSGRuYzJWallqSnllWG8zY25WNmJteHpjV2RtTkhBemVqVm1NQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVFdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFMUxURTVVbVZoY2pJdFJsTXVhbkJuSWpzZ1ptbHNaVzVoYldVcVBWVlVSaTA0SnljeE5TMHhPVkpsWVhJeUxVWlRMbXB3WndZN0JsUTZFV052Ym5SbGJuUmZkSGx3WlVraUQybHRZV2RsTDJwd1pXY0dPd1pVT2hGelpYSjJhV05sWDI1aGJXVTZDbXh2WTJGcyIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--ae89d426f1f28cfcdf14dfa70f03c767aa01b38b/15-19Rear2-FS.jpg - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:59 209.115.235.218 60176 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_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--8165500c1e1645f6defeeaa959ef7fa6ac43e659/DALL%C2%B7E%202023-12-06%2014.35.19%20-%20Create%20an%20image%20that%20features%20a%20wide%20banner%20with%20a%20background%20pattern%20of%20black%20carbon%20fiber.%20Add%20dynamic%20splashes%20of%20mud%20across%20the%20banner,%20as%20if%20mud%20.png - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:59 209.115.235.218 60167 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkemhwYjJwbE5XUnJiR0kwTkRjemJXWndabk40Wnpjd09IWnhZZ1k2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpYldsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFMUxURTVRMmhsZGpOcGJtTm9VSEpsY25WdWJtVnlMWFJvZFcxaUxtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuTVRVdE1UbERhR1YyTTJsdVkyaFFjbVZ5ZFc1dVpYSXRkR2gxYldJdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUTZFWE5sY25acFkyVmZibUZ0WlRvS2JHOWpZV3c9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--e1a4f59eb90fffb78601d97be3a83c1da0abe4c9/15-19Chev3inchPrerunner-thumb.jpg - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:59 209.115.235.218 60180 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhjREp5TURaM1lUazJNakJ3WkdVemVYZHJOR2h6YkhKdFptWndaQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVFdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpJd01URXRSbTl5WkMxUWNtVXVhbkJuSWpzZ1ptbHNaVzVoYldVcVBWVlVSaTA0SnljeU1ERXhMVVp2Y21RdFVISmxMbXB3WndZN0JsUTZFV052Ym5SbGJuUmZkSGx3WlVraUQybHRZV2RsTDJwd1pXY0dPd1pVT2hGelpYSjJhV05sWDI1aGJXVTZDbXh2WTJGcyIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--da14663b4859585715b3ec37761193ca0ed0414c/2011-Ford-Pre.jpg - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:59 209.115.235.218 60174 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkSFoxTkhWdU4yUTVOamRwYzJJNU5ucHFhR053WnpNMGFEaDVOQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVTJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFMUxURTVRMmhsZGxOMFpXRnNkR2d1YW5Cbklqc2dabWxzWlc1aGJXVXFQVlZVUmkwNEp5Y3hOUzB4T1VOb1pYWlRkR1ZoYkhSb0xtcHdad1k3QmxRNkVXTnZiblJsYm5SZmRIbHdaVWtpRDJsdFlXZGxMMnB3WldjR093WlVPaEZ6WlhKMmFXTmxYMjVoYldVNkNteHZZMkZzIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--7433e4073cbf604589aeb9fa1b3ffb0460a16c64/15-19ChevStealth.jpg - 400 - URL -
2023-12-12 22:32:59 209.115.235.218 60181 10.50.7.10 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhjakZ1YTJSc2FHNW5hamN3Tm1FMk0ySXhaakJoYm5GbFlXUnBiUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpUjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpFeFptOXlaRjl3Y21VdWFuQm5JanNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1VxUFZWVVJpMDRKeWN4TVdadmNtUmZjSEpsTG1wd1p3WTdCbFE2RVdOdmJuUmxiblJmZEhsd1pVa2lEMmx0WVdkbEwycHdaV2NHT3daVU9oRnpaWEoyYVdObFgyNWhiV1U2Q214dlkyRnMiLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--9c49fc8cba46d06a2f9d3bdd7e18484352fcd724/11ford_pre.jpg - 400 - URL -
```

I could fix this issue by unchecking "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" under ARR -> Server proxy settings but this isn't ideal because we want all requests to be proxied through IIS since the spree backend does not have a SSL cert and will ideally not be open to the internet.

How do I fix this issue? Is it a problem with the generated URL?

Comment: Why are you using `redirectType="Found"` if it's a rewrite?

Comment: Since the requests aren't reaching IIS, it's possible that the request breaks one or more rules enforced by HTTP.sys, you can try to solve by creating DWORD values under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` as IIS machines: `AllowRestrictedChars = 1`  `EnableNonUTF8 = 1`.

Comment: @samwu I tried that. Then restarted the machine. It still gives the same error.

Comment: @Dai that was an oversight. removed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! The request was breaking http.sys rules. I modified it as suggested by @samwu by creating DWORD registry values under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

AllowRestrictedChars 1
EnableNonUTF8 1
UrlSegmentMaxLength
```

Along with allowing restricted characters and NonUTF8, I had to increase the UrlSegmentMaxLength from 260 (default) to max.

More details on how to do this at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/iisadmin-service-inetinfo/httpsys-registry-windows